# Passing credential to a Delphi TWebBrowser component

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE11 to develop a small application to retrieve info from a password protected website.
So far I have placed a TWebBrowser on a form and use "Navigate" to load the page. After I login with my credentials, I create a filter on the webpage.
I have successfully parse all the pages that result from filter and saved on the disk useful information.
The link are like this:

```
"https://membri.listafirme.ro/pagini/p1.htm#selectie"
"https://membri.listafirme.ro/pagini/p2.htm#selectie"
"https://membri.listafirme.ro/pagini/p278.htm#selectie"
```

Now my problem is that when I want to use the same component to navigate (in the same session I believe) on one link that exist on the page, is navigate on a page without credentials and therefore with partial information.
Is there a way to pass the credentials?
Or what to do to stay logged?
I'm a loosing the session?
tks alot
Razvan

Comment: You need to automate the login process by running a custom script.

Comment: Sounds like the site is using HTML authentication rather than HTTP authentication. In which case, after a successful login, the browser should get a cookie to identify the login until the browser session ends. As long as you are working in the same browser session, and have cookies enabled, you should be fine.